# In Spring Boot 2.1 how do you configure Netty to use a custom EventLoopGroup?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux

I'm trying to configure Netty to use custom EventLoopGroup and custom port.

According to documentation I see that I can use `WebServerFactoryCustomizer`

```
@Configuration
public class NettyCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<NettyReactiveWebServerFactory> {

        @Override
        public void customize(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory) {
            factory.addServerCustomizers(new EventLoopNettyCustomizer());
        }
    }

    class EventLoopNettyCustomizer implements NettyServerCustomizer {

        @Override
        public HttpServer apply(HttpServer httpServer) {
            EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(50);
            return httpServer.tcpConfiguration(tcpServer ->
                    tcpServer.bootstrap(serverBootstrap
                            -> serverBootstrap.group(eventLoopGroup))).port(9000);
        }
    }
```

but when I apply this bean I see the following exception in console.

```
2019-03-21 19:38:18.872 ERROR 30981 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

    org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start Netty
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer.start(NettyWebServer.java:75) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext$ServerManager.start(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:232) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.startReactiveWebServer(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:67) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at com.refinitiv.keyvalue.train.Main.main(Main.java:10) [classes/:na]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: group set already
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.group(AbstractBootstrap.java:86) ~[netty-transport-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
```

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948033/how-to-customize-netty-with-spring-boot-2-1-webflux) in Stackoverflow, but I can't figure it out how to make it work and which way one is correct.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48607114/how-to-set-event-loop-pool-size-in-spring-webflux-webclient?rq=1help?

Comment: And does the standard server.port option not work for Netty as the documentation suggests it is used regardless of the specific server implementation?